# Wizardry before Harry Potter

Tags: creative-writing, character-development, self-publishing

I'm writing a book about the hidden wizard world that spread and broke because of the fear of being shown up and it's the first book that starts the series, the adventure is about one guy lead the whole wizard world to get together and to establish a ministry and schools to develops the wizarding world. There's a villain as well. The start of the story and the villain is a bit similar to the start of the Harry Potter series and to Voldemort as well. But they are not the same. Just touch and go one. Any comments?

Comment: Are you planning to write about the wizarding world described in Harry Potter (if so, you can't, that would be plagiarism) or another world inspired by the series that differs in important aspects? Even in the second case, that sounds like a question you need to ask a lawyer.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of bits and pieces of knowledge around concerning witches and wizards. If you are concerned about doing something similar to Harry Potter, maybe use other known aspects that aren't included in that series. Research can be fun.

Don't use terminology you can find all the time in Harry Potter (like "wizarding world"). Avoid big cliches you may find in there. Maybe have a different system/set of laws for magic.

Take your own originality and throw it in there to make it your own. If I've learned anything from reading and trying to write, it's that no matter what your idea is (even if you thought of it before you saw anything like it outside of your head), it's been done before in some form or another. You just take the ingredients we all use and combine them in your own way, with your own spice added to it.

Also, if your book is *inspired by* the Harry Potter series at all, that's super cool, but it could potentially be a recipe for similarity (maybe). I'm guilty of similar things. I've heard that exposing yourself to more reading material can get new ideas in your head. Push yourself outside your comfort zone and pick up on whole new concepts. Then you'll have more material to work with, and it won't be too similar to one book series.

Stay creative

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a great idea! You should definitely go for it! Just make sure you don't use too much of the Harry Potter series, though it's okay to get inspiration from it! The book that I'm trying to write, I started because of inspiration from the "Harley Merlin" series, so it's okay to have inspiration! Make sure to put a GINORMOUS spin of you onto it, okay?

Be you forever!